# Can I automatically generate unit test cases for some PHP code?

Tags: php, unit-testing

I have a legacy PHP site that is up and running,

We are required to make modifications, and the original programmers are long gone, they left behind a purely procedural PHP code with no unit tests whatsoever.

Is there a way to automatically generate unit tests from the production web site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to generate *sensical* unit tests from the production site.

How would such a test generator know what rewrite rules you have configured in your web server to even hit code on disk?  Even if it knew that or there were no rewrite rules, how would this test generator know how to generate code for a reasonable number of paths?  I've seen some scripts that make the assumption of a request always getting the same result and throwing an exception if they don't, but that isn't a good thorough test, and it doesn't even apply in all cases.

Besides, if your code is purely procedural, good unit testing becomes difficult.

Comment: Maybe he is referring to generating some templates or some stubs?